# Update an item using MS Flow VS Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow2013, ms-flow

I have a business scenario where i want to update some fields based on the user selection on drop-down field. now i have 2 approaches to follow:-

1. Update the Item using MS Flow
2. Or Update the Item using Workflow 2013

now i first went with the MS Flow, as it is the newer and recommended way, but the main issue which i faced with MS Flow is that if i update the item using MS Flow this will cause the MS Flow to get executed again and again, while updating an item inside workflow 2013 will not cause another instance of MS Flow to get triggered. so is my assumption correct? and can i prevent the MS flow from getting triggered if i update an item inside it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This depends on the Flow trigger conditions you set.**

For example, when the status of the item is 2, the item will update. Even running the workflow, if not the item status changed to 1, Flow still working.

[image]